# Lacoste shirt during the prayer

Tags: salat, clothing

Is it allowed to wear the following Lacoste shirt during the prayer? please give proper reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well. There is a difference of opinion. Some scholars say your prayer will valid but you will sin for wearing a shirt with an animate creation. Others say it is not valid you praying in a shirt like that (Source: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/83154/ruling-on-praying-in-a-garment-on-which-there-is-a-picture-of-an-animal-or-a-person)

I would err on the side of caution and not wear it. I am assuming you have other shirts that you can wear. Furthermore, the shirt itself should be thrown away as it has a animate picture on it.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.